# parse text and get tow values using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text:

```
$D('make').onChange('s',123456789,'a',10)
```

The target is to get values **123456789** and **a**

Please help to create regex expression to parse a string.

ps
Im using javaScript but i think at all laguages the result will be the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Split by comma and take 1st and 2nd index elements.

Comment: thats good solution! but the task is to use regex. sorry

Comment: Don't feel sorry, split also uses regex i.e. `/,/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through `string.split` function.

```
> var s = "$D('make').onChange('s',123456789,'a',10)";
undefined
> s.split(/,'?|'?,/)[2]
'a'
> s.split(/,'?|'?,/)[1]
'123456789'
```

Comment: This solution is better becouse number may contain more or less numbers? for example 112 or 55555555555. So thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = str.match(/,(\d{9}),\'([a-z]{1})\'/);

console.log(res[1]);
console.log(res[2]);
```